# My Slideshow isn't working. Images are placed on top of one another

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

Basically, I tried using some code from w3schools to create a image slideshow for a website I am making in my se1400 class, but when I tested the code, all of my images were stacked on top of one another, the text was placed over each other, and the buttons used to move through the slideshow were only visible on one of the images.

I overlooked my code, ran it through some validators and fixed any spelling mistakes that I made but nothing seems to work. Here is a look at what I added:

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.slideshow-container {
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="images/darkgrass.jpg" alt="picture of grass" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="images/dirt.jpg" alt="picture of dirt" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="images/plant.jpg" alt="picture of plant" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @SegaSonic-88, welcome to StackOverflow.  In order to help you with your question, can you please make sure you've posted a complete & runnable code sample here (for example, I can tell from your HTML that your `slideshow-container` is missing, and your <img> tags are pointing to local files that live only on your computer, so we can't see them).  That being said, I went and cleaned most of this up myself, put it [here in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds8nLkb5/), and I have to say that it looks to be working just fine, so please also elaborate on exactly what issue you are seeing.

Comment: You can see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for tips on posting informative and debuggable examples, and in your case, it would be really nice to see this as a runnable StackOverflow Snippet (the `<>` icon in the StackOverflow toolbar), which is basically just like having a JSFiddle right here in your post.

Comment: Sorry if I mislead you with my question, but through a little bit of tweaking to my code, I was able to get it to work, all that I needed to do was place my javascript code within my html file, not sure it that is the best way to do that, but it works!